# Accesing camera from other devices on webpage

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I'll describe my problem briefly. I made a page that access the webcam to shot a picture and then upload it to my server. When I access the page on my localhost, it works perfectly, the problem occurs when  I try to access from another device or I access with the IP.. For example: http://localost/Project/Page works well, but http://192.168.0.5/Project/Page doesn't work.

This is the code I used to access te media. The error occurs in the else sentence and throws the alert

```
    navigator.getUserMedia ||
        (navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false }, onSuccess, onError);
    } else {
        alert('your browser doesn't spport this function');
    }
```

I don't know if the code isn't working or if there is a security policy making my page crash.

Regards

Comment: What does it mean "isn't working"? It highly depends on the security settings of your browser. However, as you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia the method returns a promise. You should properly catch the exception and check its content, as it can throw several kind of it...

Comment: Thanks for answer. I alredy added the try{ }catch{ } section and now it throws "navigator.getUserMedia is not a function"

Comment: Put a breakpoint _before_ this row: `navigator.getUserMedia ||
        (navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);` and inspect.

Comment: However: `navigator.getUserMedia` is deprecated! Switch to compatible `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Solution. I had to add a " security exception" to the browser, and it worked. Maybe not the best practice but the cheaper one when you dont have a SSL certificate. [image]